# How to write on common partition on Ubuntu after dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, drive

I have a total of three partitions on my internal SSD. One is used for windows, the second is for Ubuntu, third is common which I use for storing my personal data. Whenever I try to paste some files on the common partition on Ubuntu, I get an error that `Not enough permission to paste files`. Also, whenever I unmount the common partition on Ubuntu, it again gets mounted on the next boot.

This is my first time using Ubuntu so I am clueless about what to do. Why does this happen and what is the solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
fstat as asked in comments:

```
cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=2d505044-4a50-463a-ab5b-8aca75f57c8a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=4C60-95AC  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: First is Windows fast start up off. Note that Windows turns it back on with updates. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation  And then are you mounting in fstat. post this in question above: `cat /etc/fstab`  See example using UUID: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions or `UUID=XXXXXXXXXXX   /media/YY ntfs defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names 0 0`